# ContainerResponseFilter - how to get content type

Tags: json, servlets, jax-rs

In this method, how can I access the content type of the response to only modify json responses? I am using this code to wrap my entity in json metadata.

```
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ContainerResponseFilter`, the `ContainerResponseContext` object contains a `MediaType`